# Setting up vue-recaptcha-v3 with Vue 2 and nuxt

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, recaptcha, vue-recaptcha

I am trying to install `vue-recaptcha-v3` with Vue 2 following the guide on `https://github.com/AurityLab/vue-recaptcha-v3/tree/vue-v2.x`, but I cannot get it to work. I need both invisible captcha and a "I am not a robot" captcha, but for now I want at least one of them working.

I installed `npm install vue-recaptcha-v3@^1.9.0`, I have a google site key,
I added the following to my `nuxt.config.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { VueReCaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha-v3';

Vue.use(VueReCaptcha, {
    siteKey: 'myRealSiteKeyHere'
});
```

And here is my difficulty - in making the captcha work in my component. I tried some different things

1. The code from the tutorial activated on button click:

```
async recaptcha() {
    (optional) Wait until recaptcha has been loaded.
    await this.$recaptchaLoaded()

    // Execute reCAPTCHA with action "login".
    const token = await this.$recaptcha('login')

    // Do stuff with the received token.
    }
}
```

Unfortunately nothing is happening here, as it looks like `this.$recaptchaLoaded()` never finishes.

2. Wait for the recaptcha to load first:

```
this.$recaptchaLoaded().then(() => {
    this.$recaptcha('login').then((token) => {
        this.recaptchatoken = token;
        console.log('Token:' + token);
      });
});
```

And here, nothing is happening.

Also, trying to reach anything related to recaptcha, it is `undefined`.

Comment: Any workarounds for this problem?